# Find object by property in object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in JavaScript and AngularJS with two properties: id and checked. I want to use a for loop to extract the find the id that matches the id of the checkbox being selected and set the checked property of that object to checked. So far I've tried the following:

### JS

```
    settings.showChecked = function (object, $event) {
        for (var x in settings.rules) {
            if (settings.rules.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                if (typeof settings.rules[id] == $event.currentTarget.id) {
                    findAndReplace(settings.rules[checked], $event.currentTarget.id);
                }
                if (settings.rules[id] === $event.currentTarget.id) {
                    settings.rules["checked"] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        console.clear();
        console.log(settings.rules);
    }
```

### HTML

```
<div class="time-check" ng-repeat="service in settings.services">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" ng-change="settings.showChecked(settings.rules, $event)" ng-model="service.checked" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-{{service.TimeValidation}}" name="check"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-{{service.TimeValidation}}" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>{{service.TimeValidation}}</span>
</div>
```

However when I run this it skips over the `typeof` condition, which I know means they're not the same type, but having trouble seeing why those two would not be the same type?

Ultimately, my end goal is to have have a list of items that have been checked which is derived from the original set of rules which contain every possible combination of options.

Comment: If you're comparing types of two properties, you need to use the typeof operator on both sides of the comparison.

Comment: Can you share the `array`?

Comment: The composition of the array is [id] = "ECOMondayAM", [cheked] = false

Comment: I see several problems with this code. You're iterating over the property names in `settings.rules` using `x` as your iterator variable. You then check if the property name in `x` is a property of the object itself rather than the object's prototype, implying that there is a prototype chain in play. But then you stop using `x` at all and start using the variable `id` which is not declared or assigned in the code snippet you shared. Then it appears you're comparing the type of one property with the id of a dom element.